# Windows: text file became binary

Tags: windows, qml, windows-10, qt-creator

I am working on a QML project with Qt Creator 4.0.0 on Windows 10.

At one point I had a blue screen, and after rebooting, the file on which I was working became binary: impossible to open it on a text editor (including vim) or to see its text content.

I tried to change the file extension, to change the encoding in Sublime Text... nothing helped.

When asking for a git diff:

```
$ git diff qml/file.qml
Binary files a/qml/file.qml and b/qml/file.qml differ
```

Does anybody have any idea about how to retrieve the file?

Comment: Notepad++ opens _anything_ (size/format) I throw at it. Sounds though, like the file-system used by windows 10 may have marked this as a 'binary-file', using data-streams not normally accessible to the user. - much like the NTFS one does with it's contents. (I.e some thumbnails and even file-data) I'd try to open with Notepad++, copy, paste into a new file and save.. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately even Notepad++ shows me some binary data when opening the file, and I did not find any way to access the original text data

Comment: Sounds like it's probably going to be little more than typing practise, unfortunately.